# Why letter M or W indent are different than other letters?

Tags: html, css, typography

Looking by this example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="lundi" value="Lundi"/>
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="lundi" >L</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="mardi" value="Mardi"/>
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="mardi" >M</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="mercredi" value="Mercredi"/>
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="mercredi" >W</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="jeudi" value="Jeudi"/>
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="jeudi" >J</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="vendredi" value="Vendredi"/>
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="vendredi" >V</label>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute!important;
  left: -9999px!important;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top:6px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family:'arial';
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 0;
  width: 32px; height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: ' '; 
  background:#ccc;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px; left: 6px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #000;
  transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.checkbox-inline{display:inline-block;}
.weekday{text-indent:-29px; margin-right:60px; font-weight:bold; }
.weekday::before{background:none!important;}
.weekday::after{z-index:-1;}
```

**Results**

[image]

I'm indenting the letter negatively to center it inside my box. As you can see, all letters except `M` and `W` are centered.

I've tried many `font-family` and nothing, still having this offset. Any typography guru out there that could explain why those twos act differently?

Note that these are `<label>` with a `text-indent` set to negative.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/warface/pLLr8pbq/

Comment: It's a very interesting question, so I spent a bit of more time playing with it, check out the [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34620453/483779), and hope that helps more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All characters have different widths except in mono-space fonts.

Rather than fighting with changing the indent, *since you already have an exact width set on those boxes*, you can **set your label width to match your box width**, *center your text*, and **remove your text-indent and left-padding** and it should solve your alignment issue for all letters:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-top:6px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family:'arial';
  width:32px;
  text-align:center;
}
.weekday{margin-right:60px; font-weight:bold; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pLLr8pbq/3/

Answer (score 2):

I think letter `M` and `W` are just wider than the others for serif and sans-serif fonts, and if you use a fixed `text-indent` value, that is not likely going to center all the `A-Z` letters properly.

I would suggest to add an extra tag around the letters, i.e. `<span>M</span>`, then set it to absolute position, and center it both horizontally and vertically by using `transform`.

```
.weekday span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Along with other tweaks, I have optimized CSS significantly, see the updated demo below. It also gives you the ability to adjust the label's size and font size easily, both the letter and the grey background will be always centered automatically both horizontally and vertically.

**[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLLr8pbq/7/)**

```css
.weekday {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'arial';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.weekday span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.weekday:after {
  content: '';
  background: #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all .2s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .weekday:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="lundi" value="Lundi" />
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="lundi"><span>L</span></label>

<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="mardi" value="Mardi" />
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="mardi"><span>M</span></label>

<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="mercredi" value="Mercredi" />
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="mercredi"><span>W</span></label>

<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="jeudi" value="Jeudi" />
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="jeudi"><span>J</span></label>

<input type="checkbox" name="jour_semaine[]" id="vendredi" value="Vendredi" />
<label class="checkbox-inline weekday" for="vendredi"><span>V</span></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a matter of alignment within its container. Try this:

```
.checkbox-inline{display:inline-block; text-align: center;}
.weekday{text-indent:-44px; margin-right:60px; font-weight:bold; }
```

Mess around with your indent to get them exactly in the center. Anything between -44px and -46px seems legit, but if you want to be pixel-perfect, have at it!

Your [**JFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pLLr8pbq/1/)

Comment: WTH, don't tell me that was only a simple `text-align:center` !! Haven't tought that could affect a single letter. Thanks m8

Comment: LOL you've probably have been staring at your PC for too long. Clearly, you would've caught this had you gone for a break ;)